# Migrating the databases using SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

I was wondering if someone could help me with creating a while loop to iterate through multiple databases(100 databases) and drop/Truncate the tables(Around 60 tables in each database) within those databases.Thank you.
My task is to create an SSIS package to move the data from source database to target database.Data in the destination needs to be truncated as part of the process whenever I run that package the old data need to be truncated and the new data needs to be inserted. 
Kindly help.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the part you need help with?

Comment: creating a while loop to iterate through multiple databases(100 databases) and drop/Truncate the tables(Around 60 tables in each database) within those databases.

Comment: drop and truncate are not synonymous. Just a heads up. Also, why not just backup your source databases and restore them to your destination?

Comment: A good old back up and restore here is so much easier to script.

Comment: My source database is a log shipping database(Standby/Readonly mode).Sorry I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just explain how i would go about this problem.

Hoping the destination and source database,tables are of similar schema.

1) Try to create a table with all the database (Source and destination) details all 60 in a separate database.

2) You need get the database details using execute SQL task from the table and use For Each container for looping the logic of truncate the destination table and then move the data from source database to destination (The data is moved from source database one after other).

3) You will need to use Dynamic SQL and stored procedures for moving the data from source database to destination database (That you must be knowing). or  You can use Data flow task too if you don't want to use Stored procedure or Dynamic Queries.

Hope it helps you! :)